# Update WadCfg "only" of existing Azure Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-rm-template, azure-diagnostics, azure-resource-group

I want to monitor Perfomance metrics of a existing Service Fabric Cluster. 
Here is the link of Performance metrics -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-generation-perf

I went through this Microsoft documentation -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-perf-wad

My problem is, The ARM template I downloaded during Service Fabric creation time is quite big and contains lot of params and I don't have the template-params file. I think it is possible to build the params file but it will be time consuming.

- Is it possible to download template and template-params file of
  existing service fabric cluster ?
- If no, Is it possible to just update the "WadCfg" section to add new
  performance counters ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you can try to use https://resources.azure.com/ to edit the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can export your entire resource group with all definitions and parameters, there you can find all parameters(as default parameters) for the resources deployed in the resource group. I've never done for SF cluster, but a quick look to an existing resource group I have I could see the cluster definition included.

This link explain how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template

In Summary:

- Find the resource group where your cluster is deployed
- Open the resource group and navigate to 'Automation Scripts'
- Click 'Download' on top bar
- Open the ARM template with all definitions
- Make the modifications and save
- Publish the updates

1: 
[image]

2:
[image]

You could also add it to a library and deploy from there, as guided in the link above.

> **From the docs**: Not all resource types support the export template function. To resolve this issue, manually add the missing resources back into your template.

To be honest, I've never deployed this way other than test environments, so I am not sure if it is safe for production.